# wmi win32_ process stdout python

Tags: python, cmd, wmi, win32-process

Im  trying to connect to remote windows machine, using win32_process to count number of files on desktop via command line of remote machine and get output.

I use WMI,

```
c=wmi.WMI('machine name',user='username',password='password')
mycommand = c.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine='cmd.exe /c  dir /a:d /s /b "C:\User\Desktop" | find /c ":\"')
```

Is there any way how to get output of this command via python (number of files)

upd. Maybe you know ANY way how to connect to remote machine, ran any command via command line (or powershell) and get output? (except paramiko, it is not working for my server).

Comment: If a remote process is not required, have you tried using a UNC name?  `DIR \\MACHINE\C$\User\Desktop` I have never done it using WMI, but PowerShell `Invoke-Command` is quite easy.

Comment: thanks, can you pls send link with description how I can do it via powershell? I did not find it...

Comment: In a powershellconsole `help Invoke-Command -Full` There is -much- information available on the Internet. https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=PoQ1X5ioA5qB-QaT_a3ABw&q=powershell+invoke-command+remote+computer+example&oq=powershell+invoke-command+remote&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgBMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOg4ILhCxAxDHARCjAhCTAjoFCAAQsQM6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOgIILjoFCC4QsQM6CAgAELEDEIMBOgoILhDHARCvARAKOgQIABANUK8TWJNJYKtZaABwAHgAgAGxA4gB6DaSAQgyLTE3LjMuM5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear way to read the output from remote Windows machine through wmi.
You can try to mount the drive and read the content.
Change localhost with the remote machine IP. here D$ refers to D directory I want to mount

```
import os
   
filename = 'example.log' 
for root, dirnames, filenames in
   os.walk('\\\\localhost\\D$\\Testdir\\'):
       for file in filenames:
           if filename in file :
               match=os.path.join(root, filename)
               f = open(match).read()
               print(f)
```

Can check more example on below URL:

https://ashishpython.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-read-files-of-computer-drive-in.html